# How to Read and Process Multiple Text files in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, file-io

Have python 3.6 script working on ubuntu 18.04 to process a single text file via torch and Bart transformer but running into 'NameError' problem when trying to read and process multiple text files from a folder. New to python.

Please note that if the following snippet is used without importing glob and os then the script runs perfectly on a single file:

```
with open('output/input.txt') as corpus:
    lines = corpus.readlines()
    lines = [line.replace("\n", "") for line in lines]
```

NameError that results from the "generate_xsum_READ_FILES.py" below. Not sure why this is happening given it's already been defined under def main(): and works with single text file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_xsum_READ_FILES.py", line 29, in <module>
    preds = bart.sample(lines, beam=4, lenpen=2.0, no_repeat_ngram_size=2, temperature=0.9)
NameError: name 'bart' is not defined
```

generate_xsum_READ_FILES.py

Would appreciate any help so I can avoid this error in future scripts. Cheers.

```
import glob
import os

import torch
from fairseq.models.bart import BARTModel

def main():
    bart = BARTModel.from_pretrained('bart_large_xsum', checkpoint_file='model.pt')
    bart.cuda()
    bart.half()
    bart.eval()

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "output", "*.txt"))

corpus = []

for file_path in file_list:
    with open(file_path) as corpus:
        lines = corpus.readlines()
        lines = [line.replace("\n", "") for line in lines]

        print("[Before]")
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            print(f"({i+1}): {line}")

        with torch.no_grad():
            preds = bart.sample(lines, beam=4, lenpen=2.0, no_repeat_ngram_size=2, temperature=0.9)
            print("\n[After]")
            for i, pred in enumerate(preds):
                print(f"({i+1}): {pred}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Working now with slight change to code. As per above etc.

```
bart.eval()

path = 'output/*.txt'

corpus = glob.glob(path)
for name in corpus:
        with open(name) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            lines = [line.replace("\n", "") for line in lines]
```

etc.

Comment: `lines = f.read().strip().splitlines()` can replace the last two lines.